# How to count number of dates before a certain date (01st March 2021)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1. I need to count the number of boxes meant for destruction for dates before 1st March 2021.  I've used this formula but it doesn't seem to work - **=COUNTIF($G$2:$G$72,">"&DATE(2021,3,1))**.
2. I would like to also use conditional formatting to highlight those dates before 31st March 2021. Your assistance is very much appreciated.

[Example File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGVIg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `>` is facing the wrong way. It should be less than (<).

To do conditional formatting, highlight all the cells you want to apply it to and then use the formula. `44256` is the number excel assigns to the date `3/1/2021`

```
=G2<44256
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. It helped with the sample excel sheet I attached but didn't work on the actual excel sheet. Not sure if the issue with the date format but I did change the date format but still unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: Well, I can't help anymore if you are unable to post a new example that illustrates your problem. Good luck!

Comment: I will try to edit my original post with the new excel sheet and hope that you could assist as I'm unable to attach the file in my earlier comment.  Anyway, your assistance is ver much appreciated.

Comment: Try `=COUNTIF($G$2:$G$22,"<"&"1/3/2021")` as far as the formula goes (based on the cell range in your sample).  As far as Conditional Formatting goes, highlight the cell range and select `Conditional Formatting` / `Highlight Cell Rules` / `Less Than` - then type `1/03/2021` in the `LESS THAN` box, and choose your desired format from the `with` box.